# How can I kill a python websocket connection ungracefully for automated testing?

Tags: python, websocket

I need to ungracefully kill a Python Websocket connection (kill -9 way) to make sure that the server removes a RabbitMQ queue associated with the connection if the client connection is lost. I am using the Python websocket client: https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/.

I am currently actually manually killing my hacky script by interrupting it on the console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but I would like to automate it.

```python
import websocket
import select
token = <token>
try:
    obj = websocket.create_connection("wss://<websocketurl>",
                                  timeout=5,
                              header={"Authorization": "Bearer {0}".format(token)})
except websocket.WebSocketConnectionClosedException:
    print ("connection closed error")
    raise

print("created")
recv_permission = "y"
while recv_permission is "y":
    recv_permission = input("y to receive data, n to end")
    ready = select.select([obj],[],[])
    if ready[0]:
        print ("data or event received, ready object: ")
        try:
            output = obj.recv()

        except websocket.WebSocketConnectionClosedException:
            print ( "closed while receive" )
            raise
    print(f"output: {output}")

obj.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`raise KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) from your code to simulate pressing Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import signal
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL);
```